# Are GC aluminum wires better than leadstone (and better fluxducts)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-thermal-expansion

In modded minecraft, the mod galaticraft adds aluminum wires. I do not have industrial craft 2 installed, and if you have that mod installed, it makes the wires bad (check the GC wiki). I have the mod thermal expansion, which adds leadstone fluxducts, and better fluxducts, that have a transfer rate limit (except the most expensive, which requires gelid cryothem, which is expensive, I haven't found a bliz yet). Does the galaticraft wires have a transfer rate limit that does not show up in game? If so, which "wire" is better?

Comment: you seem to be asking a different question in the title than the post

Comment: No, I am asking which is better. Transfer rate is the only thing that is good about wires (unless you are playing IC2) and is what is different between each wire